# Passing a value into a jQuery UI dialog box with a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is my document.ready code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dialogbox").dialog({
        open: function(event, ui) {$("a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close").remove();},
        bgiframe: true,autoOpen: false,closeOnEscape: false,draggable: false,
        show: "drop",hide: "drop",zIndex: 10000,modal: true,
        buttons: {'Ok': function() {$(this).dialog("close");processEmp();}}
  });
});
```

I have the following JavaScript code that takes one parameter:

```
function test(pEmp)
{ 
  var a = pEmp.value);

  $('#dialogbox').dialog('open');
}
```

My question is, based on the value that I pass into my test function, which in turn calls my jQuery UI dialog ('#dialogbox'), when the user presses the 'Ok' button in the dialog, I need to somehow (which is what I am not sure how to do), pass the the variable "a" which holds my pEmp.value, into my other function processEmp(a?), which I have attached to my 'Ok' button.

I basically need this value when the user acknowledges the dialog box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may pass custom option to dialog before opening it:

```
$(function () {
     $("#dialog").dialog({
          open: function (event, ui) { $("a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close").remove(); },
          bgiframe: true,
          autoOpen: false,
          closeOnEscape: false,
          draggable: false,
          show: "drop",
          hide: "drop",
          zIndex: 10000,
          modal: true,
          buttons: { 'Ok': function () {
               $(this).dialog("close");
               processEmp($(this).data("pEmpValue"));
          } 
          }
     });
});

function processEmp(a) {
     alert(a);
}

function test(pEmp) {
     $("#dialog").data("pEmpValue", pEmp.value).dialog("open");
}
```

Or even the simplest solution is to declare `a` variable in scope of the window:

```
var a = null;

$(function () {
     $("#dialog").dialog({
          open: function (event, ui) { $("a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close").remove(); },
          bgiframe: true,
          autoOpen: false,
          closeOnEscape: false,
          draggable: false,
          show: "drop",
          hide: "drop",
          zIndex: 10000,
          modal: true,
          buttons: { 'Ok': function () {
               $(this).dialog("close");
               processEmp(a);
          } 
          }
     });
});

function processEmp(a) {
     alert(a);
}

function test(pEmp) {
     a = pEmp.value;
     $("#dialog").dialog("open"); 
}
```

Comment: This looks like unsupported behavior and I would be reluctant to rely on it. The docs say the option method is for passing a 'dialog option' which I take to mean one of the defined options.

Comment: @BNL, you have a point. In this question suggested to use .data() method instead of the custom option: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-custom-options-in-jquery-ui-dialog

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by adding an event handler for 'close'. Something like this:

```
$("#dialogbox").bind("dialogclose", function(event, ui) { processEmp(a); });
```

Comment: It can also be specified in the original options by `close` (just like the OP bound `open`).

Comment: Appreciate your help @Dmitry but I am not sure how I hook this in with my code above. Do I still keep my 'Ok' button in my dialog?

Comment: Yes, you should keep 'Ok' handler to close the dialog. When dialog closed 'dialogclose' event would fire.

Comment: Yes, remove the call to processEmp from your Ok button handler and move it into the close handler. The Ok button's handler still calls the close method.